# Yii2 set session timeout - I am unble to set session timeout in yii2

Tags: session, yii2

Below is the configuration I used backend/config/main.php in my application But still I am unable to set session timeout.

```
   'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'authTimeout' => 3600,
    ],'session' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\Session',
        'cookieParams' => ['httponly' => true, 'lifetime' => 3600 * 4],
        'timeout' => 3600*4,
        'useCookies' => true,
    ],
```

My requirements are
1.Expire session if inactive of user more than 30 minutes 
2.If browser is closed, don't set session expire before 30 mins.

Thank in advance

Comment: `'enableAutoLogin' => false,`

Comment: It will work if we did this, but We want this settings as true only